# Free Wi-Fi mapper and diagnostic software

Tags: gratis, wifi, signal-processing, diagnostics

I'm looking for something like [NetSpot](http://www.netspotapp.com/) to create a map that visually shows Wi-Fi parameters (like signal, SNR, etc).

### Requirements

- Record Wi-Fi data in an easy way that can be done in different locations.
- Create a visual gradient map that shows gathered diagnostic data.
- Free.

### Optional

- Can show detailed information/reports about gathered Wi-Fi data.
- Multi platform.
- Open source.